# Can I resolve DNS based on the calling clients source IP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, cdn

Given a Windows 2008 or 2008 R2 DNS Server and a well known list of internal subnets, can I resolve DNS entries different based on the IP of the calling client?

Essentially, poor man's CDN where I divide my regional Clients into subnets and point them at different servers?

I want to avoid spinning up a Linux/BIND Box, but from what I gathered Windows 2003 didn't have the ability, so no idea of 2008/R2 gained that?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're after, but it sounds like you're after round robin and netmask ordering. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842197

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks! That sounds like it goes in the right direction. Basically I have this: Client in Europe, Client in Asia, Client in the US. Servers in these three regions. Centralized DNS. Europe Client asks DNS and gets Europe Server, Asia gets Asia and US gets US. DNS decides this by looking at the Clients IP. Netmask Ordering sounds like it would do that.

Comment: Glad to help and hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after round robin and netmask ordering.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842197